# Can't import PIL after installing Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have python 3.x, and was told to install Pillow for image manipulation. After installing it with pip however, i'm unable to import PIL from the python interpreter. It just says `ImportError: No module named 'PIL'`. Running `pip list` in the command line shows that Pillow is indeed installed.

Comment: Does `pip -V` mention python 2.x or python 3.x?  If it mentions python 2.x, you need to install Pillow with `pip3` instead.

Comment: it says python 3.5 on the end.

Comment: And when you start your Python interpreter, you see a 'Python 3.5.x ...' header at the top?

Comment: I am absolutely sure I have python 3 installed. I wouldn't forget using various python 3 specific features.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to import `PIL`?

Comment: And yes, it says Python 3.5 (64-bit)

Comment: `import PIL`; that's all i'm typing.

Comment: And I get the same error when trying `from PIL import Image`

Comment: Create a clean virtualenv and try to install again: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments - also include the exact commands you use to install in the question

Comment: I don't really have the time or the means to create an entire virtual machine just for the purposes of testing this one problem. The only command I ran was `pip install pillow`

Comment: I uninstalled PIL with pip, and then installed it via easy_install with the command `easy_install pillow`. It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up installing correctly after using easy_install instead of pip.

Answer (score 1):

You might have used `pip` for a different `python` executable. To make sure that the correct `pip` command is used, run:

```
$ python3 -m pip install pillow
```

---

> I don't really have the time or the means to create an entire virtual machine just for the purposes of testing this one problem.

`virtualenv` is not a virtual machine. All you need to create a virtualenv from scratch:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv # install package
$ python3 -m virtualenv venv # create virtualenv named 'venv'
```

Then [to activate the created virtualenv on POSIX system](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#activate-script):

```
$ source venv/bin/activate # activate on POSIX
```

Or on Windows:

```
C:\> venv\Scripts\activate
```

Now, `python`, `pip` commands refers to the virtualenv. To deactivate virtualenv, run:

```
$ deactivate
```

Comment: It turns out that I actually had both the 32 and 64 bit versions of python 3.5 installed at the same time, and pip was installing over the 32 bit version by default. I was trying to import it from a 64 bit command line, so it wasn't working. I uninstalled the 32 bit version and reinstalled pillow using pip, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the environment in which your "pip install" operation is inconsistent with the environment in which your project is running, you can check as below:

- first: input "pip which", if console display"/cygdrive/c/Users/u3656/.virtualenvs/projectname-XQq1ahMp/Scripts/python", means you now in the project's environment, you should use "pipenv install pillow" to install pillow.
- second：if console display" /cygdrive/c/Users/u3656/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python" means in system environment, you should input "pipenv shell" to enter the project environment, then follow the operation as first.
- third: don't forgot to chg your interpreter to virtual environment.(if you use vscode : at the lower right corner of window [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q990.png))